# Select rows from table inserted through the past week

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I need to select all rows added in the last week in the database.

This is for a "Top 5" page which should show the most sold products over the past 7 days. I tried:

```sql
SELECT order_id
FROM orders
WHERE order_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(week,-1,CURRENT_DATE) AND NOW()
```

which returns this error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1,CURRENT_DATE) AND NOW() LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Other things I have tried were simply the same query but with other syntax not working on this sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need below

```
SELECT order_id FROM orders 
WHERE order_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mysql try this to get last weeks data

```
SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```